# C++ Randomized Quick Sort Bug

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quick sort algorithm but somehow Im having a bug and I just can't fint it, my randomizedPartition seems to be working fine. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int  randomizedPartition(int *v, int start, int end);
void quickSort(int *v, int start, int end);
void swap(int *p, int *q);
void print(int *v, int len);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  cout << "QUICK SORT:\n" << endl;
  int v[]      = {6, 4, 7, 3, 0, 1 , 2, 9, 19};
  int len = sizeof(v)/sizeof(int);

  cout << "Before Sorting: " << endl;
  print(v, len);
  cout << "After Sorting: " << endl;
  quickSort(v, 0, len - 1);
  print(v, len);

  return 0;
}

int  randomizedPartition(int *v, int start, int end) {
    int len = (int) abs(end - start + 1);
    srand (time(NULL));
    int idx      = rand() % len;
    cout << "IDX RD: " << idx << endl;
    int pivot    = v[idx];
    swap(&v[start], &v[idx]);

    int i = start - 1;
    int j = start;

    for (int posi = start + 1; posi <= end; ++posi) {
      if(v[posi] <= pivot) {
        ++i;
        ++j;
        swap(&v[posi], &v[i]);
        swap(&v[posi], &v[j]);
      }
    }

    cout << "Pivot: " << pivot << endl;
    cout << "Pivot Index: " << (i + 1) << endl;
    return ++i;
}

void quickSort(int *v, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
      int idx = randomizedPartition(v, start, end);
      print(v, end - start + 1);
      cout << "Start: " << start << endl;
      cout << "End: " << end << endl;
      cout << "idx - 1: " << idx - 1 << endl;
      cout << "idx + 1: " << idx + 1 << endl;
      quickSort(v, start, idx - 1);
      quickSort(v, idx + 1, end);
    }
}

void print(int *v, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    cout << *(v + i) << " ";
  }
  cout << "\n" << endl;
}

void swap(int *p, int *q) {
  int temp = *p;
  *p = *q;
  *q = temp;
}
```

Can anyone help me to finde the bug ? Here is one of the possible outputs:

```
Before Sorting: 
6 4 7 3 0 1 2 9 19 

After Sorting: 
IDX RD: 2
Pivot: 7
Pivot Index: 6
4 6 3 0 1 2 7 9 19 

Start: 0
End: 8
idx - 1: 5
idx + 1: 7
IDX RD: 5
Pivot: 2
Pivot Index: 2
0 1 2 6 3 4 

Start: 0
End: 5
idx - 1: 1
idx + 1: 3
IDX RD: 1
Pivot: 1
Pivot Index: 1
0 1 

Start: 0
End: 1
idx - 1: 0
idx + 1: 2
IDX RD: 2
Pivot: 2
Pivot Index: 3
0 1 6 

Start: 3
End: 5
idx - 1: 2
idx + 1: 4
IDX RD: 1
Pivot: 1
Pivot Index: 4
0 3 

Start: 4
End: 5
idx - 1: 3
idx + 1: 5
IDX RD: 1
Pivot: 3
Pivot Index: 7
0 9 

Start: 7
End: 8
idx - 1: 6
idx + 1: 8
0 9 6 2 1 4 7 3 19
```

Comment: Never seen a quicksort quite like that. Usually there is one swap in the loop, not two, and one swap at the end.

Comment: And `srand` should be called once per program, usually at the top of `main`, not repeatedly. srand reseeds the random number generator. If you have no idea what that means or why you don't want to do it, [start reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand).

Comment: None of the above will fix your bug (and watch out, thanks to `using namespace std;` you may not be calling the `swap` you think you are), so I think someone's going to have to march through the algorithm with a debugger. Might as well be you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index in `randomizedPartition` should be `start + rand() % len`, not just `rand() % len`.

Also, as a side note, your `print` function isn't actually doing what you want it to. You want it to print the elements `start` through `end`, but it's actually printing `0` through `end - start`. Your debugging process and your coding process in general would benefit from trying to keep things clean and simple. The code is a bit of a mess right now which makes it harder to debug.

Comment: Haven't run it, but I think this fix will produce the correct answer. Still fails to implement quicksort, though. Too many swaps

Comment: Thank you so much, the only thing that I had to change was exactly that one, and everything works well now.

Comment: @user4581301, even with though I have those extra swaps,the running time is still linear since this set of swaps are executed in constant time. And once Im using a randomized version worst case of qSort is n log(n)

Comment: Two things: 1. That's really bad thinking in the modern world, @PJ_. You're going to find a lot of low Big O algorithms that run poorly on a processor with good branch prediction and caching. Linked lists being a stand-out fail. You have the same Big O, but you're still doing twice the work you need to do. 2. You aren't generating random numbers. If you look closely you'll see that `rand` is spitting out the same number each time in a given run.

Comment: Another take away is if the marker looks at the code, not just the results, they'll see that you haven't implemented quick sort. If the requirement is implement quicksort, you may receive a lower grade. You are close to a Lomuto quicksort. You might as well finish the job and maximize the grade.

Comment: @user4581301 This exercise was just to work on my programming logic, I was not looking on a perfect implementation and I didn't wanted to just look to the book. And I also tested the rand() and indeed was generating the same value but that stopped from happening after I used srand (time(NULL)), after that I was getting different values each time.

Comment: One last piece, @PJ_ : Here is your code with the print statements removed, the offset fixed, and the generated random number printed out http://ideone.com/hQVKNC Run it and note how you always get the same number.